# Mysql update column based on distinct column

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a large order table.  The order table with a few hundred thousand order records and recently add a new column invoice_no and I need to create the invoice_no value based on distinct (user_id,seller, addtime) for the old order record.

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST_ORDER`(  
  `ORDER_ID` INT(11),
  `USER_ID` INT(11),
  `SELLER` VARCHAR(50),
  `ADDTIME` INT(11),
  `GOODS_NAME` VARCHAR(50),
  `PRICE` FLOAT(11,2),
  `INVOICE_NO` INT(11)
);

INSERT into `TEST_ORDER` (`ORDER_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`, 
`GOODS_NAME`, `PRICE`, `INVOICE_NO`)
values('1','1','AMAZON','1399109546','BOOK 1','10',NULL);

INSERT into `TEST_ORDER` (`ORDER_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`, 
`GOODS_NAME`, `PRICE`, `INVOICE_NO`) 
values('2','1','AMAZON','1399109546','BOOK 2','20','NULL');

INSERT into `TEST_ORDER` (`ORDER_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`, 
`GOODS_NAME`, `PRICE`, `INVOICE_NO`) 
values('3','2','EBAY','1438582766','BOOK 3','10',NULL);


INSERT into `TEST_ORDER` (`ORDER_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`, 
`GOODS_NAME`, `PRICE`, `INVOICE_NO`) 
values('4','2','EBAY','1438582766','BOOK 4','20',NULL);


INSERT into `TEST_ORDER` (`ORDER_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`, 
`GOODS_NAME`, `PRICE`, `INVOICE_NO`) 
values('5','3','AMAZON','1399109546','BOOK 1','10',NULL);
```

The expected result

[image]

Can this be done by normal update sql query or I need to write a store procedure and loop every order record to check the order belong to same invoice_no?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this could be done with one update command, however you need to apply some trick to get the running number of invoice using the distinct data and then update with self join. The query would look like

```
update TEST_ORDER t1
join (
  select 
  ORDER_ID,
  @rn:= if ( (@prev_uid = USER_ID && @prev_seller = SELLER && @prev_addtime = ADDTIME),@rn,@rn+1) as rn,
  @prev_uid:= USER_ID,
  @prev_seller:= SELLER,
  @prev_addtime:= ADDTIME
  from TEST_ORDER , (select @rn:=0,@prev_uid:=0,@prev_seller=null,@prev_addtime:=null)x
  order by USER_ID,SELLER,ADDTIME
)t2
on t1.ORDER_ID = t2.ORDER_ID
set t1.INVOICE_NO = t2.rn
```

Here is a **demo**

```
mysql> select * from TEST_ORDER ;
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
| ORDER_ID | USER_ID | SELLER | ADDTIME    | GOODS_NAME | PRICE | INVOICE_NO |
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
|        1 |       1 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 1     | 10.00 |       NULL |
|        2 |       1 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 2     | 20.00 |       NULL |
|        3 |       2 | EBAY   | 1438582766 | BOOK 3     | 10.00 |       NULL |
|        4 |       2 | EBAY   | 1438582766 | BOOK 4     | 20.00 |       NULL |
|        5 |       3 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 1     | 10.00 |       NULL |
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+

mysql> update TEST_ORDER t1
    -> join (
    ->   select 
    ->   ORDER_ID,
    ->   @rn:= if ( (@prev_uid = USER_ID && @prev_seller = SELLER && @prev_addtime = ADDTIME),@rn,@rn+1) as rn,
    ->   @prev_uid:= USER_ID,
    ->   @prev_seller:= SELLER,
    ->   @prev_addtime:= ADDTIME
    ->   from TEST_ORDER , (select @rn:=0,@prev_uid:=0,@prev_seller=null,@prev_addtime:=null)x
    ->   order by USER_ID,SELLER,ADDTIME
    -> )t2
    -> on t1.ORDER_ID = t2.ORDER_ID
    -> set t1.INVOICE_NO = t2.rn;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from TEST_ORDER ;
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
| ORDER_ID | USER_ID | SELLER | ADDTIME    | GOODS_NAME | PRICE | INVOICE_NO |
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
|        1 |       1 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 1     | 10.00 |          1 |
|        2 |       1 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 2     | 20.00 |          1 |
|        3 |       2 | EBAY   | 1438582766 | BOOK 3     | 10.00 |          2 |
|        4 |       2 | EBAY   | 1438582766 | BOOK 4     | 20.00 |          2 |
|        5 |       3 | AMAZON | 1399109546 | BOOK 1     | 10.00 |          3 |
+----------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks you very much and is work.  However, the invoice number is select from a function call.  SELECT nextval('invoice_no') AS invoice_no.  How should i replace the @rn+1 with this function call?

Comment: i replace the sql to get the invoice_no from nextval but is not working.

Comment: I did not get ? If you have a table as you provided where the invoice num is null at the beginning then running the above query would reset them in the table, meaning it will update table and then just doing select would give you the result as expected. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: what happen is the invoice number was introduce a few month ago, so only the last 3 month record with the invoice number.  Now IT is asking me to patch the old order record with the invoice number.  The programmer is using the nextval function to get the latest invoice number, basically is like a sequence number.  What i can do is to find the last invoice number and set @rn= last invoice number.

Comment: i replace @rn=0 to the last invoice number 20000.

Answer (score 1):

I think as variant you can try this

```
UPDATE `TEST_ORDER` SET `INVOICE_NO` = CRC32(CONCAT(`USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`))
```

but.. crc32 will give u alot of dupes..
this will certainly help:

```
UPDATE `TEST_ORDER` SET `INVOICE_NO` = CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(CONCAT(`USER_ID`, `SELLER`, `ADDTIME`)) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10)
```

it will have no dupes for millions of records.

also change `INVOICE_NO` from `INT` to `BIGINT`

Answer (score -1):

You can set the invoice column value to user id using this statement:

```
update TEST_ORDER SET INVOICE_NO=USER_ID
where INVOICE_NO IS NULL;
```